# Gridview not showing data for a particular field in linq

Tags: linq, gridview

I want to data in gridview for a particular mail_id. but wheneven i add this where condition its not showing anything. please help

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    var mail = lblmail.Text;
    var result = from test in je.jobposting orderby test.post_date where test.c_j_email==mail  select test;
    foreach (var items in result)
    {
        gvjob.DataSource = result;
        gvjob.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you verify any rows were returned?

Comment: still not working after removing foreach @grundy

Comment: how you remove it? :-) i mean remove only foreach declaration, but set up `datasource` and `databind` don't remove

Comment: @SayantanDas you should add the ASP markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this better?

```
{
  var mail = lblmail.Text;
  // here, I assume jobposting is a DataTable
  if (0 < je.jobposting.Rows.Count) {
    var result = from test in je.jobposting orderby test.post_date where test.c_j_email==mail  select test;
    if (result.Any()) {
      gvjob.DataSource = result;
      gvjob.DataBind();
    } else {
      Response.WriteLine("No Match for c_j_email=" + mail + ".");
    }
  } else {
    Response.WriteLine("<b>No Data in jobposting DataTable!</b>");
  }
}
```

Comment: Added a count checker - **may not be right, so check it. I don't have VS here**. Are there any records returned?

Comment: i think `result.Any()` better than `0 < result.Count()`

Comment: Thanks, Grundy. I made that change.

Comment: `Any()`  return bool, so `result.Any()` enough

Comment: Then my guess is the string `lblmail.Text` is not in the `test.c_j_email` collection.

Comment: I added another test condition. What is **je.jobposting**? A DataTable?

Comment: Error 1 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<JobPortalModel.jobposting>' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<JobPortalModel.jobposting>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: jobposting is the table name in the databse, and je is a entity